# problem with mysql stored procedure when working in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MySQL and now i hava a project which must work with MYSQL. It's a win application and I use C# on Visual Studio 2010. I tried to write a simple stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetBank`()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM BANKNAME;
END
```

And my C# code is here:

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dowacodb;UID=root;PASSWORD=123456");
  con.Open();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("GetBank", con);
  cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cm);
  da.Fill(dt);
  con.Close();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

My test is to show the data in datagridview when clicking the button. It shows fine on the first click but when I click again, the data in datagridview is gone. The next click will show the data again and repeatedly.

But this code will be perfect when not working with stored procedured

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dowacodb;UID=root;PASSWORD=123456");
  con.Open();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("Select * from bankname", con);
  cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cm);
  da.Fill(dt);
  con.Close();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

So what's wrong with MySQL? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved! Instead of using ordinary way to interact with MySQL: open a connection, create a command and use a data adapter to fill datatable, I use a MySQLHelper class and it works fine for me:

```
DataTable dt = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dowacodb;UID=root;PASSWORD=123456", "call getbank()").Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

But now I wonder why this way works while the older way doesn't ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to call your procedure in MySQL is

```
CALL GetBank()
```

so

```
MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("CALL GetBank()", con);
```

should do it. Which also removes the need to specify that your command *cm* is a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your concern! This solution i tried too but its result was still the same